# .TrimEnd seems to group parameters

Tags: c#, string, trim

I've got a string containing a processname like

string name = "firefox.exe", now I need to remove only the ".exe" part, so I get the processname without the ending. I tried to use

```
   Console.WriteLine("output: " + processName.TrimEnd('.','e','x','e'));
```

But for some reasons output seems to be "firefo" without the "x". Any idea how to get this solved in an easy and clean way?

Comment: [FileName without extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask it to trim the characters `.`, `e` and `x` from the end, so it does that:

```
firefox.exe
firefox.ex
firefox.e
firefox.
firefox
firefo
```

> how to get this solved in an easy and clean way?

Using [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() solved :).